Error: ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT error in react-native-udp
I create two separate application. My first application is a mobile application and second application is tv application. When I send message from the client application, I get this:

Error: ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT

Mobile app
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [ipAddress, setIpAddress] = useState(''); // Set this to the TV's IP address
  const client = UdpSockets.createSocket({type: 'udp4'});

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if (!message || !ipAddress) {
      console.log('Message or IP address is missing.');
      return;
    }

    // Send the message to the TV IP address and port
    client.send(message, 0, message.length, 8888, ipAddress, error => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Message sent successfully to IP:', ipAddress);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    client.bind(8082, () => {
      console.log('Client bound to port 12345');
    });
    client.on('message', (messageData: any) => {
      console.log(messageData.toString());
    });
    return () => {
      client.close();
    };
  }, []);

TV app
 useEffect(() => {
    const startServer = async () => {
      const server = UdpSockets.createSocket({type: 'udp4'});

      // Get IP Address of the TV for logging
      const ipAddress = await NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address();
      console.log(`Server IP address: ${ipAddress}`);

      server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
        console.log(
          `Message received: ${msg.toString()} from ${rinfo.address}:${
            rinfo.port
          }`,
        );
      });

      server.bind(8888, () => {
        console.log(`Server is listening on 8888 ${8888}`);
      });
    };

    startServer();
  }, []);

I am not able to send data to my tv application.
